# Removing duplicates in a Python list by id

Tags: python, list, duplicates

I build large lists of high-level objects while parsing a tree. However, after this step, I have to remove duplicates from the list and I found this new step very slow in Python 2 (it was acceptable but still a little slow in Python 3). However I know that distinct objects actually have a distinct *id*. For this reason, I managed to get a *much* faster code by following these steps:

- append all objects to a list while parsing;
- sort the list with `key=id` option;
- iterate over the sorted list and remove an element if the previous one has the same id.

Thus I have a working code which now runs smoothly, but I wonder whether I can achieve this task more directly in Python.

**Example.** Let's build two identical objects having the same value but a different *id* (for instance I will take a `fractions.Fraction` in order to rely on the standard library):

```
from fractions import Fraction
a = Fraction(1,3)
b = Fraction(1,3)
```

Now, if I try to achieve what I want to do by using the pythonical `list(set(...))`, I get the wrong result as `{a,b}` keeps only one of both values (which are identical but have a different *id*).

My question now is: what is the most pythonical, reliable, short and fast way for removing duplicates by *id* rather than duplicates by *value*? *Order of the list doesn't matter if it has to be changed.*

Comment: figured it out! deleted my comments.

Comment: `Fraction` is a bad example, because if you're trying to do this with a standard library class you can't. You can't change the rules `set` uses, you'd have a build a set-like class of your own (perhaps a thin wrapper around a dictionary keyed on ID). However, if you're actually using a class you control, you can implement `__eq__` as shown below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should override the [`__eq__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__) method so that it depends on the objects `id` rather than its values. But note that your objects must be hashable as well, so you should define a proper [`__hash__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__) method too.

```
class My_obj:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.val)

    def __eq__(self, arg):
        return id(self) == id(arg)

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.val)
```

Demo:

```
a = My_obj(5)
b = My_obj(5)

print({a, b})
{5, 5}
```

Comment: This is a very convenient answer as I use my own class; adding `__hash__` and `__eq__` should be very easy; in this specific case, can I make `__hash__` return the _id_ as a quick way of implementing this method (since my little class is a private one and only exists during the execution of a function and actually is even defined in the body of this function)?

Comment: @ThomasBaruchel Why you want to do that? the `hash` function is the safest way to go for creating hash values for objects. Because it guarantees  to produce random (in python 3) and different values for different variables.

Comment: I was asking that because `__hash__` needs to return an integer, and in this step my class (which describes a node in a tree) doesn not embed many usable values but rather lists of other nodes; for that reason I was wondering which significant value I could hash. I tried to make `__hash__` return the _id_ and it works well (still faster than my previous attempt), now with `list(set(...))`. Is it the way to go?

Comment: @ThomasBaruchel It will work because you don't need the hash value and it'll depend on the `__eq__` method, so as far as you use `id` for comparison there is no problem.

Answer (score 4):

Be, careful because discrimating by `id` may fail with some basic types where python optimizes storage when possible:

```
a = "foo"
b = "foo"
print(a is b)
```

yields

```
True
```

Anyway, if you want to handle standard objects (even non-hashable ones) you can store them in a dictionary with they `id` as key.

Example with fractions:

```
from fractions import Fraction
a = Fraction(1,3)
b = Fraction(1,3)

d = dict()

d[id(a)] = a
d[id(b)] = b

print(d.values())
```

result:

```
dict_values([Fraction(1, 3), Fraction(1, 3)])
```